# God's forgiveness

Tags: possessives

The genitive 's refers to what belongs to you. I say Jack's car. I mean the car belongs to Jack. I could also say, 'his car' using possessive adjective. My question is about 'God's forgiveness'. It is God who forgives, so it should be 'man's forgiveness' because  'forgiveness is **to** man' and it was **'from'** God. Why is the phrase 'God's forgiveness' grammatical, I have a confusion.

to pray for God’s forgiveness

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/forgiveness?q=forgiveness

Comment: 'Apostrophe s' can refer to what belongs to you, what is given or produced by you, or what pertains to you. _Shakespeare's plays; Cadbury's chocolate; Risso's dolphin_ (named after the first scientist to describe it).

Answer (score -1):

In this case man is **forgiven**, and God **forgives**.

This means that **forgiveness** is God’s to give, and man’s to get.

The forgiveness is **FOR** man, but it is **FROM** God.